# firebase deploy with specific target name still deploys to all targets in that type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, google-cloud-sdk

#### What I'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to specify which set of storage rules to upload using deploy targets.

#### What I'm running and its result

`firebase deploy --only storage:backupStorage`

But still the resulting deployment is as follows below. And as you can see, both `storage.rules` and `storage-backup.rules` are being uploaded:

```
i  deploying storage
i  firebase.storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
i  firebase.storage: checking storage-backup.rules for compilation errors...
+  firebase.storage: rules file storage-backup.rules compiled successfully
+  firebase.storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  storage: uploading rules storage.rules...
i  storage: uploading rules storage-backup.rules...
+  storage: released rules storage-backup.rules to firebase.storage
+  storage: released rules storage.rules to firebase.storage
```

#### Some setup information

Running `firebase target` gives:

```
[ storage ]
backupStorage (my-project-backup)
mainStorage (my-project.appspot.com)
```

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "storage": [
    {
      "target": "mainStorage",
      "rules": "storage.rules"
    },
    {
      "target": "backupStorage",
      "rules": "storage-backup.rules"
    }
  ]
}
```

My `.firebaserc`:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "my-project": {
      "storage": {
        "backupStorage": [
          "my-project-backup"
        ],
        "mainStorage": [
          "my-project.appspot.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets and tried to figure out what I have missed.

Any idea what I have overlooked? All hints or tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a trouble report to the Firebase team and got excellent support. It turns out I didn't miss anything. It was a bug in Firebase. They've escalated it internally and I asked the engineer I emailed with if they could write a public ticket so I could track it. He did, and here is the link if anyone else is interested:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3496